# TS error running treeview after adapting for React TS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I installed the package react-treebeard

https://react.rocks/example/react-treebeard

To allow me to have a nice out of the box tree control for my React TS website which allowed searching etc. The online demo all works fine, however it is in ReactJS so there are some modifications I have had to make to translate it to TS syntax. However there are two problems

1) When I click on a node, it crashes out with

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'cursor' of null
>   Content../src/Content.tsx.Content.onToggle
>   C:/src/investment/src/signoff/src/Content.tsx:94
>   91 | // }   92 |    93 | private onToggle(node: any, toggled: any) {
>
> > 94 |     const {cursor} = this.state;   95 |     if (cursor) { cursor.active = false; }   96 |    97 |     node.active = true;

and

2) The tabbing and indenting of the tree nodes is wrong - I assume I've not included some styling component somewhere but can't see what as I would have thought it was all in the node module package downloaded by npm install react-treebeard

The second one is less an issue as I can work through that, I just mentioned it in case something glaring jumps out. However the first one seems to be a basic problem with me not converting it to TS syntax correctly so hoping someone can spot the issue.

My component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import {Treebeard} from 'react-treebeard';

import data from './components/treebeard/data';

interface IContentState {
  data : any,
  cursor : any
}
class Content extends React.Component<{},IContentState> {


  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.setState({cursor: null});
    this.setState({data: data});
    this.onToggle = this.onToggle.bind(this);       
  }

  public render() {
    const stateData = {
        children: [
            {
                children: [
                    { name: 'child1' },
                    { name: 'child2' }
                ],
                name: 'parent',
            },
            {
                children: [],
                loading: true,
                name: 'loading parent',
            },
            {
                children: [
                    {
                        children: [
                            { name: 'nested child 1' },
                            { name: 'nested child 2' }
                        ],
                        name: 'nested parent',
                    }
                ],
                name: 'parent',
            }
        ],
        name: 'root',
        toggled: true,
    };

    return (
      <div className="Center-content">
        <div className="Tree-control">
            <Treebeard data={stateData}
                        onToggle={this.onToggle}/>
        </div>        
      </div>
    );
  }

private onToggle(node: any, toggled: any) {
    const {cursor} = this.state;
    if (cursor) { cursor.active = false; }

    node.active = true;
    if (node.children) { node.toggled = toggled; }

    this.setState({cursor: node});
  }
}

export default Content;
```

Answer (score 0):

You setState the value of `cursor: null,` change it to true or false, null values always cause unexpected crashes. You should avoid putting null values on your components also I think you were trying to have this `this.state = { cursor: null }`
As far I can see you have no state